# Confusing error using F# Active Pattern

Tags: f#

Why does this compile:

```
let (|T|F|) b = 
    let f (o:int) : obj = null
    if b then T else F(f)
```

while this fails:

```
let (|T|F|) b = 
    let f (o:obj) : obj = null
    if b then T else F(f)
```

The difference between the two examples is the argument 'o' is coerced to either an 'int' (compiles) or an 'obj' (fails to compile)

Comment: I can't help but wonder what your goal is.

Comment: Yes, I know its odd code. I'm writing some reflection code over F# types and the active pattern returns a function which operates on 'obj'. The code I posted is obviously useless :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an unfortunate type inference corner case.  This will work:

```
let (|T|F|) b : Choice<unit,obj -> obj> =   
  let f (o:obj) : obj = null
  if b then T else F(f)
```

In your original code, despite your annotation `(o:obj)`, F# infers that `o` could actually be of any type `'a`, which leads to a generic active pattern of type `bool -> Choice<unit,'a -> obj>`.  Because `'a` is a free type variable, F# won't accept this active pattern definition.  You can see a similar problem if you do something like:

```
let (|T|F|) b =   
  if b then T else F []
```

Again, the solution would be to monomorphize the definition:

```
let (|T|F|) b : Choice<unit,int list>  =   
  if b then T else F []
```